# Update using join executes only ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two rows. These rows using same ItemID but different Quantity and RowID.

When I execute the query shown below, it seems that code runs only once:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
Update t1 
Set t1.Stock = t1.Stock + t2.Quantity
From Inventory t1 
Join InventoryTrans t2 On t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID  
Where t2.RowID In (26221, 26222)
```

My expected result in stock should be 3. But for some reason is 1

Comment: Why would you expect it to run the statement 3 times? It's **one** statement. You're thinking SQL working programmatically; it doesn't because it's not a programming language. You need to aggregation if you want to `SUM` of the values.

Comment: I don't expect to run three times. I expect to run two times. One for each row. In first update stock will take value 1 and in second update stock will be  1(Previous update) +2 (current update) =3

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: If Stock starts with 0. Then my desired output in stock will be '3'  . 1 + 2  = 3 (For quantity column)

Comment: Again, that isn't how SQL works; a statement only runs one, no matter how many rows it might return. `SELECT * FROM sys.databases` doesn't run *n* times, where *n* is the number of databases you have on your host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate here. Most likely this:

```sql
UPDATE I
SET Stock = I.Stock + IT.TotalQuantity
FROM dbo.Inventory I
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
                  FROM dbo.InventoryTrans ca
                  WHERE ca.ItemID = I.ItemID
                    AND ca.RowID In (26221, 26222)
                  GROUP BY ca.ItemID) IT;
```

Note I also use meaningful aliases. Don't use aliases it's `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, as they are meaningless and won't be consistent. See [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Thank you, your code works but why it affects 3 rows? and dont affect only this two rows?

Comment: With no sample data, impossible to know, @George .

Comment: It updates all rows from First table. I want to update only rows where are joined each other

Comment: The above *will* only `UPDATE` rows that return a row from the subqyert, @George . So that *suggests* that every row in `Inventory` has a related row in `InventoryTrans ` with where `RowID` has a value of `26221` or `26222`. Again, without sample data, I cannot tell you more.

Comment: Not quite: you need `GROUP BY ()` or `GROUP BY ca.ItemID` otherwise you will get a scalar aggregate and therefore always have a row even if there is no join results, see https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html. Effectively it becomes the same as `OUTER APPLY` unless you force a vector aggregate

Comment: I generally prefer the empty set, because it makes I feel it more obvious what is going and why the seemingly redundant `GROUP BY` should not be removed.